# UISearchBar opening a second TableView with no results

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController that consists of a Label, Button, SearchBar and TableView.

Here is how the view looks like, and the flow of it (as well as the problem).

[image: Layouts]

I have two outlets for both views

```
@IBOutlet weak var _searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var _tableView: UITableView!
// ...
self._searchBar.delegate = self
```

When a search is done I capture it here:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if let query = searchBar.text {
        print("Search query: \(query)")
        //Fetch data from CoreData and update datasource array
        self._tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I fetch data from Core Data with a `NSPredicate`, rather than to filter already existing data.

Fetching data works fine, however when anything is being typed I am presented with another TableView that just says "No Results", even if data is being found by the search. I can click "Cancel" and then I can see the data that was fetched in the normal TableView.

How can I make this data display in the TableView that is being automatically opened?

I tried also assigning the `SearchBar` as the `HeaderView` of the `TableView`, but that made everything just disappear.

Comment: do you have a UISearchController anywhere?

Comment: No, I saw that in a few tutorials but I cannot find that control in the UI editor. I tried manually creating it but I can't assign my own SearchBar to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you already did, but you need to implement another `UISearchBarDelegate` Method:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    // Only update the top / Search Results table view here...
}
```

If you could provide the entire code for this functionality, we could give you better feedback.

This is the working solution (remember, searchController should be an instance variable, not a local one):

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for products or activities"
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
        searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.colorPrimary()
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Products", "Activities"]
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        // Prepare our tableView
        self._tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        self._tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        self._tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self._tableView.delegate = self
        self._tableView.dataSource = self
        self._tableView.register(ProductViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: ProductViewCell.identifier)
        self._tableView.register(ActivityViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: ActivityViewCell.identifier)
        self._tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource Methods

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return NumberOfRows
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Return a Result Cell
    }
}


extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    // MARK: UISearchControllerDelegate
    public func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    // MARK: UISearchResultsUpdating
    public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let query = searchController.searchBar.text {
            print("Search query: \(query)")
            //Fetch data from CoreData and update datasource array
            fetchData()
            self._tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print("search")
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print(searchText)
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I access the search result table?

Comment: Same way you did for the 'searchBarSearchButtonClicked' method. Take the searchText argument in this case, make the query, and use results to populate the Search Results Table View.

Comment: The problem here was that the table view did populate, but the search results table view was empty. How do I get a reference to the search results table?

Comment: If you are using UISearchController - I believe you'll have to create and configure a separate table view for search results (UISearchDisplaycontroller, which is outdated, used to have a searchResultsTableView property, but the new class does not have one). Or maybe you can use the same Table View for both cases, not sure if you'll be able to do so, because I see you also have a segmented control.

https://possiblemobile.com/2015/05/uisearchcontroller-vs-uisearchdisplaycontroller/

Comment: Here is an example using one table view: https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: If you really have to use 2 table views, you'll have to create the second one, and hide / unhide it as needed, based on the events related to the search.

Comment: I don't need to use two table views, it's just that it seemed to generate another one automatically as the result table view, and leave the one I set up in the background. I moved on to using `UISearchController` now as suggested, and this is what I have so far: https://pastebin.com/0T3JcS8Y but delegate methods are not being called when I press search. Am I doing something wrong? @ppalancica

Comment: 'let searchController' should be an instance variable, not a local one. The way you're doing is wrong, and it will get deallocated short after exiting the method where you declare it.

Comment: Ah garbage collection got me. Thank you very much, this has been bugging me for a day and a half. If you add that part to your answer I will mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `UISearchController` comes with its own searchbar. It is not available in the UI editor (but the deprecated `UISearchDisplayController` and the `UISearchBar` are still present - Don't use them if you can). You'll have to add the `UISearchController` manually in the code (and remove your `UISearchBar`). It's worth it.

At the end, your code might look like something like this (I don't deal with the TableView protocols here) :

```
public class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate  {

//Create the UISearchController (and sets the results to be displayed in the same controller
// (TableView?) as the searchable content)
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Sets self as the Search Controller's delegate
    searchController.delegate = self

    //Sets self to be responsible for updating the contents of the search result controller
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self        

    //Add the searchBar to the tableview header
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    //Avoids the white area when pulling the seachbar (not mandatory but can help)
    tableView.backgroundView = UIView()

    //SearchBar aspect (same comment)
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Find the stuff"
    searchController.searchBar.setTextFieldColor(color: UIColor(hex: 0xBBBBBB, alpha: 1.0))


    //Do your other things
}

//MARK: UISearchControllerDelegate
public func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}

// MARK: UISearchResultsUpdating
public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let query = searchController.searchBar.text {
        print("Search query: \(query)")
        //Fetch data from CoreData and update datasource array
        self._tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```